# Do Americans pronounce 'are' as 'do' in "What are you waiting for"

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, american-accent, accent

It seems a stupid question, but I already hear American on TV or movies or even songs, say `Are` like `Do` in this context

> What are you waiting for

I just listened to it again in this song

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJtDXIazrMo

Am i right please? or it is really pronounced as `are`

Comment: Are you hearing 'waddaya'? [I didn't listen to the link, but that would be my first thought.]

Comment: We typically slur those words together.  What you are hearing as a 'd' and interpreting as the word "do" is really the 't' in *what* that has been softened into a 'd' and run together with the word 'are' which has been reduced to nothing more than an a schwa and then run in with 'you'.  @Tetsujin- notes that this is typically written as *waddaya*.  Although in her song, she really pronounces it more like *waddayou*.

Comment: I'd write this as "What're you waiting for". Like Jim says, the words are slurred together. But for other commenters, if you listen to the video (at about 1:10), the "you" part is pretty well distinct from the "what're" part.

Comment: @ThePhoton- +1 "What're you" is exactly right.

Comment: To me, it sounds like "Wha-dar you waiting for".

Comment: Another common variation for what-are-you is "watcha"

Comment: @Jim Has the 'T' been "softened" to a 'D'? I thought so, but now I am not too sure.

Comment: At what time in the song does the relevant "are" (or "do") occur?

Comment: The singer of this song, Ellie Goulding,  was born and raised in England, and speaks a dialect of British English.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I listened to the song to confirm what you were asking. What you are hearing is a slurring of the words. American English gets very lazy in some contexts and informal contractions are made during speech only. In American English it's a lazy slur.  "What are you waiting for," is slurred to, "whadda you waiting for." Which can very much sound like, "what do you waiting for," if you don't know what you are listening to.

Comment: This is not American English getting very lazy. It is normal English pronunciation. As well, this singer, an *English* woman, sings 'wanna' and 'gotta', also showing that speakers of British English also pronounce these words in this fashion, which is also frequently ascribed to AmE only. Analogies with other languages are helpful to few, and they are not encouraged on ELL.

Comment: I've updated to remove the French part. However, American English in this context IS lazy. It takes more effort to form a T than a D. AE infrequently uses a T when a T is called for in "What." If you replaced the T with a D, you can slur the word, "Whaddo" and "Whadare" easier. If you use a T, there is a necessary break in "What do," and more effort in "Wha tar." Some regions that have such variance from English proper that they don't use a letter at the end of the word, "What," but instead use a glottal stop. Like Boomhauer from "King of the Hill", the Cockney dialect, and Foghorn Leghorn.

Comment: "Lazy" as compared to what? What do you mean: when a 'T' is called for? Who calls for it? The spelling? Surely, you don't think that spelling dictates pronunciation, at least not in English (of any variety). Dang, most Brits I know add an -r sound at the end of words whose spelling ends in a vowel. Like *Americar* or something. What are you talking about "English proper"? What is English Proper? I am a native speaker of American English; what is your background?

Comment: This answer isn't acceptable. Are all Americans lazy? It's their English you're gonna learn. So with this logic, you need to stop jogging every morning and sit on the couch eating French fries.

Comment: I suggest this link from *BBC Learning English* about [Connected Speech](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/multimedia/pron/connected/index.shtml).

Comment: [For instance](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/multimedia/pron/progs/prog3.shtml), in *British English*, when one says "handbag", one actually says "hambag". The *d* is gone, and the *n* has changed to its voiced equivalent *m*. And, OMG, the British also say "Wouldjou" and not "Would (pause) you?" And, for heaven's sake, "Do you want to" becomes "djwanna?"

Comment: "American English gets very lazy in some contexts" - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kRUh0aJ_8ew (MAR, that doesn't equate to all Americans are lazy, good try though). Language isn't a discrete change from one location to the next unless separated by geographical barriers. A Massachusetts accent doesn't disappear 10 miles out, but changes gradually with distance, which is why I qualified it "in some contexts". Don't get panty-bunched and change my words.

Comment: user6951 - There is only 1 way to pronounce a T. It's the first phoneme when you say, "tee". You don't say "dee". Any variation from the sound of "tee" is a variation, not "proper" or the center or normal part of the curve. If you have not heard of "New York Proper", or "English Proper", then perhaps you're not as well versed as you thought. However, it's the core; not inclusive of the outliers. The more formal (or proper or closer to the core) people speak, the more they enunciate. The lazier they get, the more they slur or drop letters. It doesn't mean it's wrong, it means it's not proper.